# Android link to own applications from other Android applications

Tags: android

i'm trying to have ability like with internal links such as Google market as :

```
market://details?id=de.schildbach.oeffi
```

for exampele

```
myApplication://detail?id=11
```

how to change manifest or create other ability for application to have that? i want to create link as `myApplication://detail?id=11` and share that in other android application such as Telegram or Whatsapp, user can be going to my application after click on my created link.

Answer (score 1):

Add an intent filter to your activity:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="myApplication"
                android:host="detail"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```

And then handle the link on your activity's onCreate(..) or onNewIntent(..)

```
    Uri intentData = intent.getData();
    if (intentData != null && "myApplication".equals(intentData.getHost()) && "detail".equals(intentData.getScheme()) {
        //link was clicked, parse the rest of intent's data and do something useful
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir. how to share created link? after share message to other application we can not click on created link to start activity, link is as text and we can not use that. please help me.

Comment: Highlighting link in another app is another app's responsibility. This another app desides by itself which URL schemes it supports. Many apps support http(s) links only, so try setting your scheme to http and your host to something which looks like domain name, e.g. "mysuperapp.com".

Comment: how to set scheme to http? can you paste simple sample?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a "scheme" as one of the intent_filter of the activity you want to be started, in your Manifest, something like:

```
<data android:scheme="@string/deeplink_scheme" />
```

You can follow Android documentation about it here :
[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)